# The difference between nb_visits_converted and nb_conversions

Tags: api, matomo

Regarding the Piwik reporting API, what are the definitions of the two keys: **nb_visits_converted** and **nb_conversions**?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a goal that can be converted more than once a visit, therefore it's possible to calculate those 2 different metrics.